# Slow Postgres Query with a SELECT DISTINCT and a Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, database-performance

We have a Postgres DB which was migrated from Oracle. There is one query which is slow in Posgres (8-11 sec) but was fast in Oracle (1-2 sec). It involves a **SELECT DISTINCT**, which several other threads have flagged as a problem in Postgres: [1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93158/how-to-speed-up-select-distinct), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177162/how-to-make-distinct-on-faster-in-postgresql). Is there something simple we can do, like add an index or something, without a major rewrite?

The query joins the table `NED_PERSON_T` with itself to get all rows whose `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is the parent value specified in the child's `NIHSERVAO`. It is a `SELECT DISTINCT` as below.

```
select
    distinct nedperson0_.ID as ID1_21_,
    nedperson0_.BUILDINGNAME as BUILDING2_21_,
    nedperson0_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED_4_21_,
    nedperson0_.CURRENT_FLAG as CURRENT_5_21_,
    /* ... + 30 other columns ... */
from
    NED_PERSON_T nedperson0_ 
inner join
    NED_PERSON_T nedperson1_ 
        on (
            nedperson1_.NIHSERVAO=nedperson0_.UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
            and nedperson0_.CURRENT_FLAG='Y' 
            and nedperson1_.CURRENT_FLAG='Y'
        ) 
order by
    nedperson0_.NIHMIXCASESN,
    nedperson0_.MIXCASE_GIVENNAME
```

The **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** gives this report:

```
Unique  (cost=362155.58..390755.66 rows=119167 width=1197) (actual time=8722.383..11202.495 rows=838 loops=1)
        Sort Key: nedperson0_.nihmixcasesn, nedperson0_.mixcase_givenname, nedperson0_.id, nedperson0_.buildingname, nedperson0_.created_date, nedperson0_.description, ... ... )
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 78016kB
        ->  Gather  (cost=103675.72..227466.24 rows=119167 width=1197) (actual time=2485.391..3100.424 rows=97678 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=102675.72..214549.54 rows=49653 width=1197) (actual time=2477.318..2880.555 rows=32559 loops=3)
                    Hash Cond: (nedperson1_.nihservao = nedperson0_.uniqueidentifier)
                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using ned_person_t_current_flag_idx on ned_person_t nedperson1_  (cost=0.43..93430.46 rows=58867 width=11) (actual time=7.536..815.779 rows=46800 loops=3)
                          Index Cond: (current_flag = 'Y'::bpchar)
                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=93430.46..93430.46 rows=58867 width=1154) (actual time=1620.284..1620.285 rows=46800 loops=3)
                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 1792kB
                          ->  Parallel Index Scan using ned_person_t_current_flag_idx on ned_person_t nedperson0_  (cost=0.43..93430.46 rows=58867 width=1154) (actual time=4.602..1226.402 rows=46800 loops=3)
                                Index Cond: (current_flag = 'Y'::bpchar)
Planning Time: 3.986 ms
Execution Time: 11218.403 ms
```

**Indexes** :

```
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_ao_test1 ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (nihmixcasesn, mixcase_givenname, uniqueidentifier)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_current_flag_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (current_flag)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_id_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_mdslink_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (nihmdslinktoadnih)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_nedid_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (uniqueidentifier)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_orgacronym_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (nihorgacronym)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_orgstat_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (organizationalstat)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ned_person_t_pk ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_sac_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (nihsac)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_temp_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (nihservao, organizationalstat, nihsac)
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_temp_idx2 ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (lower(nihmdslinktoadnih), current_flag, nihservao, organizationalstat, nihsac)
```

**STATISTICS ON NED_PERSON_T** :

```
select count(*) from ned_person_t
```

Total Count = **1243733**

```
select count(*) from ned_person_t where current_flag = 'Y';
```

with CURRENT_FLAG = Y: **142540**

```
select count(*) from ned_person_t where nihservao is not null;
```

with non-NULL NIHSERVAO: **644852**

```
select count(distinct nihservao) from ned_person_t;
```

Distinct NIHSERVAO: **928**

Comment: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 78016kB, that looks like your work_mem is pretty small. Could you change this to for example 10MB and try again? It's the sorting where you loose a lot of time

Comment: Sorry isn't it 78 MB? You mean bump it up by 10 MB, or change to 10 MB (a smaller value)?

Comment: Sorry, no I meant 100MB (at least). You can set it just for this query for testing by using SET work_mem TO '100MB';

Comment: Thanks we'll give it a try, but first I wanted to see if something could be done on the index or query level.

Comment: I think your problem is DISTINCT by 30 columns, If you have IDs you could just distinct the ID col and then Join the Other fields After this. How fast is the query without distinct?

Comment: You don't seem to use any columns from the joined table `nedperson1_`. So it's probably better to rewrite this to an EXISTS condition. Then you can remove the DISTINCT completely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Rewriting with EXISTS reduced it from 8-9 sec. to 6 sec, still very slow.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - No luck, still 9-10 sec after 'SET work_mem TO '100MB'. No discernible difference.

Comment: @geneb.  Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the EXISTS form of the query, run with the larger setting of work_mem.

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @geneb.  Please also show Oracle's plan.

Comment: The sorting on disk should be gone, with enough memory there is no need for a slow sort on disk.

Comment: I posted the new EXISTS query and the new ANALYZE The query initially takes  7 sec now. See my answer with more info.

Comment: Please post your indexes as *text*, not as image. Also, the core of `CREATE TABLE ned_person_t ..` and cardinalities. How many rows, how many with `CURRENT_FLAG='Y'`, roughly how many duplicates per `nihservao`? Why `uniqueidentifier` *and* `id`?

Comment: All done, OP updated with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EXISTS` query looks good.

Only 142540 of 1243733 rows have `CURRENT_FLAG='Y'`.
And only 644852 have `nihservao IS NOT NULL`. (Combination with the 1st line matters.)
No cases of `uniqueidentifier IS NULL`.

If you query on that condition regularly, a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)  should be very efficient. I suggest these two:

```
CREATE INDEX ON ned.ned_person_t (nihservao)
WHERE current_flag = 'Y' AND nihservao IS NOT NULL;
```

Since you only need to return `uniqueidentifier` and `fullname` (like you later commented) - and if `fullname` isn't too big - a [**covering index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) can help some more. (Requires the table to be vacuumed enough.)

```
CREATE INDEX ON ned.ned_person_t (uniqueidentifier) INCLUDE (fullname)
WHERE current_flag = 'Y';
```

Example:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)

While being at it check whether all your many indexes are actually (still) used. This one is completely redundant, **remove it**:

```
CREATE INDEX ned_person_t_id_idx ON ned.ned_person_t USING btree (id)
```

`id` is already covered by the unique index `ned_person_t_pk` (which could really be a `PRIMARY KEY` instead of just a unique index).

The final sort operation is of lesser importance as only `844` rows remain.

Comment: There are no entries where UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is NULL. We'll run this shortly and let you know, thanks a lot.

Comment: Will this also improve the original SELECT DISTINCT query, or just the EXISTS re-write?

Comment: @geneb.: Should help either query, but don't use the inferior `DISTINCT` variant.

Comment: For some reason, the 2 partial indexes didn't really make a difference. The EXISTS query by itself, *with or without these indexes*, did drop from ~8sec to ~4-5sec, on closer inspection, so the EXISTS re-write was indeed an improvement. We finally brought it down to ~1sec by eliminating all the 28 columns we didn't need and just returning the 2 we did need, UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and FULLNAME, and that made the drastic difference.

Comment: @geneb.: I added a bit for your updated scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to make your EXISTS query run fast is an index on `(current_flag, nihservao)` (or maybe partial index on nihservao filtered on current_flag) so that it can use an index-only scan to get the nihservao values without needing to jump to random parts of the table for each row. It would require keeping the table well-vacuumed for this to be effective.

If many of your other queries also focus only on current data, then it might make sense to partition your data by current_flag, to keep the relevant data more densely packed.  That is more drastic than just creating an index, though.

Comment: Somehow the partial queries which you alluded to (and so did Erwin Brendstetter in his reply) didn't make a big difference. But actually, the EXISTS query by itself did drop to ~4 sec, contrary to what I wrote earlier, so that is indeed an improvement. Also, it turned out we only needed a couple of columns, not all 30, so returning just those 2 , with the EXISTS by itself, finally brought it down to 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

As more information, per the advice above, I (1) rewrote the query with EXISTS, (2) increases MEM_SIZE to 100 MB. But this still takes 7 sec. Below is the EXPLAIN. If I re-run this query sequentially afterwards it takes much less time due to caching, but the first run takes about 7 sec., as you see below.

**UPDATE: The Exists re-write did cut the time by half, to about 4 sec.** This run wasn't really representative, we tried a few more (after disconnecting/reconnecting) and the EXISTS was better on average by about half.

QUERY:

```
select
    nedperson0_.ID as ID1_21_,
    nedperson0_.BUILDINGNAME as BUILDING2_21_,
    nedperson0_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED_4_21_,
    nedperson0_.CURRENT_FLAG as CURRENT_5_21_,
    /* ... + 30 other columns ... */
from
    NED_PERSON_T nedperson0_ 
    where
        exists (select uniqueidentifier from ned_person_t nedperson1_ 
                where nihservao = nedperson0_.uniqueidentifier and nedperson1_.current_flag = 'Y'
                )
        and 
        nedperson0_.current_flag = 'Y'
    order by
        nedperson0_.NIHMIXCASESN,
        nedperson0_.MIXCASE_GIVENNAME
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Sort  (cost=139290.39..139293.75 rows=1344 width=1195) (actual time=7627.351..7627.441 rows=844 loops=1)
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 882kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=97523.64..139220.55 rows=1344 width=1195) (actual time=5112.442..7621.895 rows=844 loops=1)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=97523.21..97531.04 rows=783 width=11) (actual time=5108.419..5109.041 rows=847 loops=1)
              Group Key: nedperson1_.nihservao
              ->  Index Scan using ned_person_t_current_flag_idx on ned_person_t nedperson1_  (cost=0.43..97172.64 rows=140228 width=11) (actual time=2.376..4999.905 rows=142540 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (current_flag = 'Y'::bpchar)
        ->  Index Scan using ned_person_t_nedid_idx on ned_person_t nedperson0_  (cost=0.43..53.21 rows=2 width=1152) (actual time=2.964..2.964 rows=1 loops=847)
              Index Cond: (uniqueidentifier = nedperson1_.nihservao)
              Filter: (current_flag = 'Y'::bpchar)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 23
Planning Time: 10.259 ms
Execution Time: 7627.670 ms
```

Comment: Yeah I did. Sorry I re-pasted from the OP. In the new EXISTS query, there is no DISTINCT, I removed it. So my answer applies to the new EXISTS without DISTINCT. I corrected my answer.